# Is $x \mapsto (x, |x|)$ locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ at $x = 0$? (there is a philosophical question)

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

**Typical Example:** $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, $f(x) = (x, |x|)$. Let manifold $M = f(\mathbb R)$.
If you ask me, "is $M$ locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ at $x = 0$?", then I would immdiately answer: "No. There is a sharp corner at $x = 0$."

I could answer this question since I know what an embedding of $M$ in $\mathbb R^2$: I can clearly define a homeomorphism $(x, |x|) \mapsto x$. With this knowledge, I could infer that since there is a sharp corner, local diffeomorphism does not hold.

Now, suppose I have a $\vee$ shape stretching out in both direction. (Of course, we know how this shape can be embedded in $\mathbb R^2$ just by looking, but let us suppose we do not know such information.) Then, how can I be so sure that $\vee$ is not diffeomorphic to the real line $\mathbb R$ at the "sharp corner?" We do not have a notion of "sharp corner" just by looking at $\vee$ itself. Moreover, is it even correct that the embedding of $\vee$ in $\mathbb R^2$ has a corner? Why cannot we assert that it is smooth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But the $\vee$ *is* embedded in $\mathbb R^2$. This is crucial information which you can't just throw away. Sure, if you strip away that information and only remember that your shape is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, you can simply give it the smooth structure of $\mathbb R$ to make it a smooth manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. But by embedding it in $\mathbb R^2$, we take the smooth structure of $\mathbb R^2$ as a reference. If this smooth structure doesn't make the $\vee$ a smooth submanifold, then that's how things are.